# Docker Flask gcloud FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, gcloud

I keep getting this error, only when I deploy my image and run it from Google Cloud Run.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory '/tmp/my_file_20230319_163330.mp3'
```

My question is, how do I store new files in a docker container to call later? I tried putting it in /tmp, but it can't seem to find it there. is it not saving there?

Code:

```
def create_audio(text):
    audio_length = 120 * 15
    file_name = None
    text = text
    overlay_type = None
    # best is 10
    overlay_volume = 15
    # default rate is 200
    # best is 300
    rate = 250
    speaker = None

    text_mp3_file = create_file(text, rate, speaker)
    audio_file = mix_audios(text_mp3_file, audio_length, file_name, overlay_type, overlay_volume)

    return send_file(audio_file, as_attachment=True)

def create_file(text, rate, speaker):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()

    file_name = f'/tmp/my_file_{datetime.now().strftime(DATE_FORMAT)}.mp3'

    engine.save_to_file(text, file_name)
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.stop()

    return file_name

def mix_audios(txt_file, audio_length, filename, overlay_type, overlay_volume):
    text_mp3_file = AudioSegment.from_file(txt_file)
    overlay = AudioSegment.from_file(overlay_file(overlay_type))

    multiplier = math.ceil(audio_length / overlay.duration_seconds)

    overlay = overlay * multiplier
    overlay = overlay[:(audio_length * 1000)]

    combined = overlay.overlay(text_mp3_file, gain_during_overlay=overlay_volume, loop=True)

    file_name = f'/tmp/my_file_{datetime.now().strftime(DATE_FORMAT)}.mp3'

    combined.export(file_name, format='mp3')

    return file_name
```

The offending line is

```
    text_mp3_file = AudioSegment.from_file(txt_file)
```

it cannot find the file which is saved here:

```
    file_name = f'/tmp/my_file_{datetime.now().strftime(DATE_FORMAT)}.mp3'
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python310
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.10

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN python3 --version

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install espeak -y
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg -y
RUN apt-get install gunicorn -y
RUN apt-get install libespeak1 -y
RUN apt-get install portaudio19-dev -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pyaudio -y

RUN echo "Installed dependencies"

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip list

CMD gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

This works locally for me

Comment: These are your options for reading and writing files in Cloud Run - https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-network-file-systems . The intro also contains some options

Answer (score 0):

It is saving there.
However, Cloud Run has [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling). Hence, not all request will go to the same instance with the recently saved file.

Although you had `manual_scaling` in your app.yaml, Google Cloud Run do not support manual scaling. If you prefer manual scaling, you could use [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) instead.

More information on Cloud Run vs Google App Engine can be found below:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/cloud-run-for-gae-customers#comparison_summary

Therefore, due to Cloud Run's autoscaling, this would then cause the FileNotFoundError.
Additionally, inactive instance will be destroyed and your recently saved file will be lost as a result of Cloud Run scaling in.

You could solve this issue by doing the one of the following:

- Saving the file to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage)
- Using [network file systems](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-network-file-systems) as suggested by [NoCommandLine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15211203/nocommandline)